# How to optimise a Matrix Multiplication so as to run faster ( non-parallel to parallel ) (.cpp)

Tags: multithreading, performance, matrix, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I need to optimize this code, using parallel technologies in order to run multiply faster. I don't understand C++ language, so I don't know what else to say.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

  void Multiply(double *A, double *B, double *C, const long size) // C = A*B
  {
    for (long i=0; i < size; i++)
      for (long j=0; j < size; j++) {
        C[i*size+j] = 0.0;
        for (long k=0; k < size; k++)
          C[i*size+j] += A[i*size+k] * B[k*size+j];
      }
  }

  void PrintMatrix(double *A, const long size)
  {
    for (long i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (long j = 0; j < size; j++)
        printf("%f ", A[i*size+j]);
      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  void Test()
  {
    long size = 3;

    double A[size][size];
    double B[size][size];
    double C[size][size];

    A[0][0] = 14.0; A[0][1] = 9.0;  A[0][2] = 3.0;
    A[1][0] = 2.0;  A[1][1] = 11.0; A[1][2] = 15.0;
    A[2][0] = 0.0;  A[2][1] = 12.0; A[2][2] = 17.0;

    B[0][0] = 12.0; B[0][1] = 25.0; B[0][2] = 5.0;
    B[1][0] = 9.0;  B[1][1] = 10.0; B[1][2] = 0.0;
    B[2][0] = 8.0;  B[2][1] = 5.0;  B[2][2] = 1.0;

    Multiply((double*)&A, (double*)&B, (double*)&C, size);

    PrintMatrix((double*)&C, size);
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    if (argc == 1) {
      Test();
    } else {
      long size = atol(argv[1]);
      printf("size=%ld\n", size);
      double *A = new double[size*size];
      double *B = new double[size*size];
      double *C = new double[size*size];
      Multiply(A, B, C, size);
      PrintMatrix(C, size);
      delete[] C;
      delete[] B;
      delete[] A;
    }
  }
```

Comment: As far as small-scale matrices are still all in-RAM, the "many-thread" approach will cost you pay way more to instantiate than it would ever pay back ( is theirs performance sense ). Before moving forwards, you might get better insight if having a look, how this code actually loads the CPU with assembly instructions and where to loops spend most of their time. Having no time-stamping to measure and read the actual code-execution time, feel free to extend the code and see your improved ( or not ) performance live : https://godbolt.org/z/v4fhE55Wz

Answer (score 0):

A high performance matrix multiplication is a surprisingly complicated topic. Start e.g. with https://doi.org/10.1145/1356052.1356053 for a description of a what goes into a fast scalar matrix multiplication (parallelism via SIMD instructions). And then continue on to https://doi.org/10.1109/IPDPS.2014.110 for a description of how to extend that approach to multiple threads.